# addEventListener() for DOMContentLoaded is not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        hideColor();
 }, false);
```

But, it doesn't seem to be binding the event  listener to DOMContentLoaded.  I have checked `document.readyState` and it says "loading". So, it means that DOMContentLoaded hasn't fired yet.

This is driving me crazy. Any ideas why it would not bind it?

Comment: Hive you tried just placing `hideColor()` before the `</body>` end tag?

Comment: How do you load this script?  Did you put it in `<head>`, at the end of `<body>` or is it loaded asynchronously?

Comment: How is the page getting generated? Is it a static file or a dynamic script? It sounds like it is a script that is not closing the connection after sending the page, thus the perpetual "loading" state.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to works just fine...

```js
function hideColor() {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    console.log(document.readyState);
    var e = document.getElementById("test");
    e.style.background = "transparent";
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", hideColor);
```

```css
#test {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```